# summarise(n=n()) returns "Evaluation error: This function should not be called directly." even when plyr is not loaded

Tags: r

I remove plyr, load dplyr and check the current packages

```
detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE)
library(dplyr)
(.packages())
```

> [1] "dplyr"     "bindrcpp"  "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices"
>   "utils"     "datasets"
>   [8] "methods"   "base"

For info here are the conflicts:

```
conflicts()
```

> [1] "filter"    "lag"       "body<-"    "intersect" "kronecker"
>   "setdiff"   "setequal"
>   [8] "union"

Then I use summarise and get the error. This is the same code that I used 6 months ago without issue.

```
by_vs_am <- group_by(mtcars, vs, am)
by_vs <- summarise(by_vs_am, n = n())
```

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: This
>   function should not be called directly.

Comment: use it in this fasion: `dplyr::summarise(by_vs_am, n = n())`

Comment: **learn more?** -> google: `"masking function r"`

Comment: Your code works in a clean R session.

Comment: @AndreElrico `dplyr::summarise` gives me the same error the OP is getting.

Comment: I did test it now. For me it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `dplyr::n()` instead.
The code should look like this:

```
by_vs_am <- group_by(mtcars, vs, am)
by_vs <- summarise(by_vs_am, n = dplyr::n())
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, this has to do with conflicts. Looking at your loaded packages and their dependences can help. For me it was the XML library, so I ran `detach("package:XML", unload = TRUE)` to fix it.